# Update range input in Vue.js 3

Tags: html, vue.js, input, slider, vuejs3

How can I update or show the actual value of a range input in Vue 3?

I thought it would be possible wiht v-model like this:

```
<input id="rangeSlider" type="range" class="form-range" v-model="value" min="0" max="5" step="0.2"/> 

            <label for="rangeSlider" class="sliderValue">
                Value: {{ value }} m
            </label>
```

Answer (score 2):

It actually works exactly the same as the Vue2, just a little bit different Vue setup

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data: () => ({
    value: 0
  })
})
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.26/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="rangeSlider" type="range" class="form-range" v-model="value" min="0" max="5" step="0.2"/> 

  <label for="rangeSlider" class="sliderValue">
    Value: {{ value }} m
  </label>
</div>
```